# program hangs with no error message

Tags: ios, xcode

When transferring to a second view controller, the new page loads. NSLog reports that ViewDidLoad and ViewDidAppear. Then the program hangs. Buttons and text fields are totally unresponsive. No error messages. Dubug pane shows the activity circle rotating. When I stop the iPad simulator, the program ends with the usual kill, quit, and exit code 0. It was almost as if program was in an infinite loop.

The strange thing is that I modified a working app, and have placed the misbehaving one and the original side by side to verify that all the delegate statements and connections were identical. One works, the other hangs.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit with code 0 means that's the debugger crash, not your app. 
However there is something not right in your app.
You might be corrupting or running out of memory, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just found the solution. I'm so embarrassed I considered deleting my question, but because someone else might run into the same problem, I'll leave it. The solution: For some reason I had unchecked "User Interaction Enabled" for the View itself. I'd examined the Enabled checkbox for all the switches, buttons, and textfields, but not the view itself. So darn simple! (And logical, of course, as all problems ultimately are!)